# (Spring Data MongoDB) Many-To-Many relational scenario

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Let's assume a **relational case scenario** like the following:

[image: Relational Case Scenario]

Where **de-normalization** results into this:

[image: After De-Normalization]

How can one represent this schema in POJOs **using Spring Data MongoDB**???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use this approach:

student_ids will be a List and create a separate class for studentInner which will have student Id, note1, etc.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Even more! If I use this class, lets say, Student_Course that has ObjectId, note1, note2, finalNote, I can use it as a field inside my Course and Student classes to represent a back and forward relation in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
@Document
public class Course {
   @Id
   private String id;

   @DBRef
   private List<Students> students;

   // Getters and setters

}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. The result would be **students: [ DBRef("students", ObjectId("...") ), ... ]**. And also, the Student class can not contain the *notes fields* because they correspond to several courses, not just one.